# Quais arquivos do bootstrap 4 devem ser incluidos em um projeto?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Baixei os arquivos do `Bootstrap 4` e vieram os seguintes arquivos:

Pasta CSS:

```
 - bootstrap.css
 - bootstrap.css.map  
 - bootstrap.min 
 - bootstrap.min.css.map   
 - bootstrap-grid 
 - bootstrap-grid.css.map 
 - bootstrap-reboot
 - bootstrap-reboot.css.map 
 - bootstrap-reboot.min
 - bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
```

Pasta JS:

```
 - bootstrap.bundle
 - bootstrap.bundle.js.map
 - bootstrap.bundle.min
 - bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
 - bootstrap.js
 - bootstrap.js.map
 - bootstrap.min
 - bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Gostaria de saber quais devo incluir e porque na versão 3 do `Bootstrap` não vinha esses arquivos `bootstrap-grid`, `bootstrap-reboot` e `bootstrap-bundle`.

No `Bootstrap 3` eu costumava inserir os arquivos `js/bootstrap.min.js` e o `css/bootstrap.min.css` além do `JQuery 3.2.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**É muito amplo**, *depende do projeto, depende da necessidade*, não dá pra afirmar.

Pode ser que se o projeto for simples somente `bootstrap.min.css` será necessário, se for um projeto que vai usar popups (apis do bootstrap) então seria necessário `bootstrap.min.css` e `jQuery` e `bootstrap.min.js`, não dá pra afirmar, eu por exemplo na maioria dos projetos uso só o `bootstrap.min.css`, mas tem projetos que uso o .js e o .css

Se for um projeto que precisa depurar, então adicionar os `.map` junto com os sources não minificados (`.min.js` e `.min.css`) pode ajudar bastante a entender algum comportamento, geralmente eu usaria somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento ou homologação.

> Sobre os map: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps

Tenho projetos que nem de jQuery necessito, geralmente é tão pouco o uso que acabo só aproveitando o sistema de GRIDs mesmo.

### O que são bootstrap-grid, bootstrap-reboot e bootstrap-bundle

Provavelmente você baixou o "source" para desenvolvimento, esse 3 juntos são o "bootstrap", se você não pretende participar como colaborador do Bootstrap ou criar um fork dele isso será interessante (baixar o source com os arquivos separados), semelhante a este projeto https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-grid, que é uma "fork"

Mas pra maioria dos projetos que pegar isolado nem seja necessário, pois acabamos por necessitar uma ou outra hora de uma funcionalidade especifica, a não ser que você necessite apenas de uma ou outra funcionalidade do Bootstrap, então pegar apenas pedaços dele pode ser útil, na maioria dos projetos usar o CDN será mais que suficiente.

Se necessitar somente do CSS adicione:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Se necessitar das APIs adicione:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### Customizando Bootstrap

Note que até o 3.3 era possivel customizar o bootstrap para baixar somente os componentes desejados http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/, no entanto parece que isto ainda não esta disponível no 4.0, mas claro que é possivel "compilar" manualmente, baixando os sources, assim como você fez

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Ótima resposta!